# No route matches [POST] "/store/index"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Learning RoR by "Agile web development with rails 4.0" and have a problem with localization selector (ch. 15.4).

In ~/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
    "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
  <div id="banner">
    <%= form_tag store_index_path, class: 'locale' do %>
      <%= select_tag 'set_locale', 
        options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s),
        onchange: 'this.form.submit()' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
      <%= javascript_tag "$('.locale input').hide()" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
    <%= @page_title || t('.title') %>
  </div>
  <div id="columns">
    <div id="side">
      <% if @cart %>
        <%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: 'cart') do %>
          <%= render @cart %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www...."><%= t('.home') %></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../faq"><%= t('.questions') %></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../news"><%= t('.news') %></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../contact"><%= t('.contact') %></a></li>
      </ul>

      <% if session[:user_id] %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to 'Orders', orders_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Products', products_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
        </ul>
        <%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In ~/app/controllers/store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart
  def index
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to store_index_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
      @products = Product.order(:title)
    end
  end
end
```

And when I select locale from selector, I have a routing error: No route matches [POST] "/store/index"

Please help.

Full project on GitHub: https://github.com/hronny/depot

Comment: The problem is likely with the POST... an index action is usually a GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your routes for index action respond only to a GET request (this is default behavior) but what you are trying to do is submit a form to this action (which is a POST request by default).

There are two ways to workaround this

1. Set your routes accordingly, as per your requirements:

   ```
   match 'store/index', to: 'store#index', via: [:get, :post]
   ```
2. Make your form submit a GET request instead of the default POST request

   ```
   <%= form_tag store_index_path, class: 'locale', method: 'GET' do %>
   ```

**EDIT**:

btw, I don't understand what your are trying to do here:

```
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to store_index_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
      @products = Product.order(:title)
    end
```

This will just redirect it back to the same action with params[:locale] and then what you will ultimately get is `Product.order(:title)`. Also, I haven't read the book in question.

Comment: This is a code from book. I think, that if using default locale (not set any locale), directly go to product.order. If set any locale, show localized product.order. Localization: I18n and YML files for different languages. So in any situation I would get product.order